# Hide history suggestions in Google Chrome temporarily

Tags: google-chrome, history

I had this awkward scenario that while on a screen share session, Google Chrome brought up a lot of suggestions from my history in the search bar when I typed in the address bar which I wasn't very comfortable with being known to the public (nothing explicit but still something I'd like *not* to share). I saw [this](https://superuser.com/q/239192/503319) question but it seems to suggest methods that would disable history even for me when I'm not on a screen share.

Another obvious option is to switch the browser while I'm on a screen share. That poses another problem in that I use a lot of the Chrome Developer Tools while debugging professionally which makes it difficult to switch to another browser (yes, some of those screen-shares involve live debugging). Also, there are certain bookmarks in my Chrome browser that I'd like to be available (internal company links, language references, etc.).

I've tried the incognito mode but it shows up search history from my sessions in the browser, even though those links haven't been ever bookmarked by me which I actually find weird. Here's the problem in Incognito mode:

[image]

That search result popup is from my **non-incognito** browsing sessions yet it shows up in the incognito search bar pop-up. This is a problem that's endemic to a lot of other sites too.

So in essence I'm seeking a way for *temporary* disablement of the search history suggestion popup while I'm on a screen share(which I guess can be extended in general to any scenario). It need not be something that automatically detects if I'm on screen-share and can instead be a manual toggle just before I go live in a screen-share.

**EDIT:**

Since this question is still unanswered, the current workaround I've employed is to create another **browser profile** and conscientiously handle my browsing habits across my professional and personal space. This helps delineate my browsing history to a large extent. There are niggles(may vary based on use case) with this approach though. Consider these situations:

- You are working in the *professional* profile. A link is shared in your internal company chat medium which isn't strictly work-related (yes, there's a lot of non-work-related chatter!). Clicking that link would open up in the currently active professional profile.
- You are browsing in the *personal* profile. An internal issue link from your company's issue tracking system is shared. Clicking that would open it up in the currently active personal profile which isn't ideal since it could quite possibly require reauthentication. The usual workaround is to switch to the professional profile and then open the link or just simply copy it on to the professional profile where one is usually authenticated already.
- Bookmarks can't be imported en masse since it would end up polluting the search space in the professional profile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thought today as I prepare for an interview.

Similar to your idea of a dedicated professional profile, haved you tried using the Guest profile? It seems to act as a temporary browsing session that gets cleared when you close the window. When you reopen the guest profile, none of your previous activity is exposed. All cookies and history are gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).